# How to retrieve the schema of a Big Query table using Airflow BigQuery Module

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, schema, airflow, google-cloud-composer

What is the easiest way to retrieve the schema of a table in big query with airflow (composer)?

I have a table in big query. For some reasons I need to use the corresponding schema of this table in an airflow (composer) DAG. No module (https://airflow.apache.org/integration.html#gcp-google-cloud-platform) seems to exist for this.

A workaround would be to use the bq command-line tool to retrieve it. Such as:

```
bq show --format=json <table> | jq '.schema.fields'
```

or

```
bq show --schema --format=json <table>
```

But I don't find that this solution is the most convenient one.

Comment: A quick glance at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py#L48) seems to indicate that there is no built-in "schema" object that you can return with your task. Maybe you can extend the class by making a custom operator class which has that functionality, look at [plug-ins](https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html)

Answer (score 0):

The BigQuery hook has `get_schema` function:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/gcp/hooks/bigquery.py

Comment: More of a comment rather then an answer